# Preposition for - "written by me ___ a branded pen"?

Tags: prepositions

**Sentence:** The exercise was written __ me __ a branded pen.

**Problem:** Fill in the blanks with apt. preposition.

**Attempt:** First blank is "by" 100% sure. Second one is either "by" or "with". I don't want to use "by" because it becomes repetitive. But, the use of "with" sounds like collaborating with a person in writing the exercise. I would say: "The exercise was written by me with Mr. John Doe" than "The exercise was written by me with a branded pen"

Have I interpreted basics of "by" and "with" wrongly? And what's the correct answer here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion,

> The exercise was written **by** me **with** a branded pen.

sounds all right. It is not incorrect and I think its the best preposition you can use. Ideally you could use "using", but then its not a preposition, but a verb.

> The exercise was written **by** me **using** a branded pen.

Comment: *by* is the option since it shows who performed the action  in this passive construction.

Comment: As in "The exercise was written by me by a branded pen" ?

Comment: No, I only meant it for the first preposition. The choice for the second one is obvious.

Comment: Yeah, that is pretty obvious too. The OP was certain about that :)

Comment: We cut with a knife. We write *with* a pen.  **Using** is not a more idiomatic choice.